# how to install custom recovery without pc

Tags: recovery-mode

I want to install custom recovery in intex aqua y2 pro  without pc to avoid accidents. i have downloaded the cwm (touch)custom recovery.img(4mb) and the stock recovery (6mb) can i flash it through mobile uncle tools without bricking it 
Please Answer

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Just saying - I think I've seen your name and similar questions here for more than 3 times before this...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but doing so could be **even more dangerous** than doing the traditional PC flashing way. Flashing it through **ADB is much easier and way less dangerous**. If you have not already tried flashing the phone, try using ADB. Also, **avoid apps like Kingoroot or Kingroot**, they are proven as spyware by the community. 
Have fun flashing your phone!  
It's **way easier than you think**
Good Luck,
 Joe.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Root your Phone to Install Recovery without PC using this Following Apps :
- **Kingroot**
- **Kingoroot**
- **Towelroot**
- **Framaroot**
- **Iroot**
Choose the one that successfully Root your Phone

Then install Flashify and grant Root Permission, then select Costum Recovery and Select the recovery.img file and flash it

Comment: I have rooted it with king root i have downloaded the recovery but flashing it through flaahify can brick my device the orignal recovery is 6mb and the custom cwm is 4mb

Comment: It's okay to Flash the Custom Recovery. Make sure your recovery.img is same as your model phone ( not the other Phone Model )

Comment: And remember to Backup current Stock Recovery via Flashify, in case everything goes wrong